# Windows 7, java 1.6.0_24 or 25m eclipse helios -->java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: windows-7, memory-leaks, java-6, permgen

I have a problem that makes eclipse modeling helios SR2 with xtext 1.0.2, crash on startup if I have projects.  If I try to update eclipse it crashes. When building workspace it crashes.

- An internal error occurred during: "Workbench early startup". 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
- !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

I am using windows 7, 64bits and jdk 1.6.0_25_b06 of 32bits and eclipse of 32 bits too.
In 64 bits all, I have more problems.

I tried configuring the eclipse .ini file but I haven't found the correct parameters for memory configuration.

I really need help with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same problem using Xtext and Helios SR2, except I'm using 32-bit windows 7. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

in your eclipse.ini you should find entries like `-Xms40m` or `-Xmx512m`
They are used to tell the virtual machine eclipse starts how much memory it may use.

You may want to use parameters like

```
-Xms64m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

That way your system can allocate up to 512 Megabyte of memory alltogether for eclpise and of that 512 up to 256 may be used for perm gen space.

Answer (score 0):

What if you close all views, and open them one by one?  Tracing a similar thing right now where the JVM suddenly adds about 4GB of RAM to its allocation when a certain Eclipse view is opened.  But this only happens when using a 64-bit Eclipse, no problem on 32-bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Select the prefrences option from eclipse option then select your web server such as Tomcat in that web server there id tab named JDK in that tab

```
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```